# Why do my TSLint rules result in errors when severity is set to "warning"?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm trying IntelliJ to create warnings when following rule is broken:

```
    "no-cross-import": [
       false,
       {
        "root": "src",
        "ignoredSources": [
        "Spec\\.ts$"
        ],
        "allowed": {
          "patterns": [
          "legacy"
          ]
        },
        "severity": "warning"
     }
    ]
```

but it always results in an error.
I've tried

```
  "defaultSeverity": "warning",
  "rules": {
     //some rules here
```

as a workaround but it also results in an error as seen in 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is `serenity` correct or a typo?

Comment: @Amy typo. fixed now :)